# HttpContext.Current is Nothing after Transfer or Rewrite

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to rewrite a url like so:

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If [some condition] Then
        Dim sPath = [fix up path]

        Context.RewritePath(sPath)
    End If
End Sub
```

The new path is correctly invoked, but when it is, `HttpContext.Current` is `Nothing`, and this breaks my code.  `Server.Transfer` and `Server.TransferRequest` have the same problem. Why is this, and what can I do to rewrite the request AND preserve the HttpContext?

**Update**: The same thing happens using the IIS Rewrite module.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the particular code that I was testing after rewrite was running in a callback in an AsyncHandler, and as such was in a background thread, which *never* has a current HttpContext, and this was true before rewrite too. In this case, other things made me notice an unrelated bug for the first time.

But in case it helps anyone else, the takeaway is:

`HttpContext.Current` **does not work** in a background thread.